# Powershell: Using Get-aduser to find the machine hostname of the PC the user is using

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use get-aduser to find the machine hostname that a user is working on.

So far I've got this but it isnt working.

```
get-aduser username -properties extensionattribute3 | select extentionattribute3
```

nothing it being returned.

Please help

Comment: `extensionattribute3` is a free Field. How you think that contains the actuale machine hostname for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, AD does not really capture that information. You could enable security audint then go to each DC in your domain, look at the security log and see where that user logged in from. But even then, I'm not sure if the host name is captured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the computer name:

```
 $objIPProperties = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
 $domainname = "{0}.{1}" -f $objIPProperties.HostName, $objIPProperties.DomainName
```

Source: http://boerlowie.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/get-the-fqdn-of-your-host-with-powershell/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP ask to know the actual hostname where User in ActiveDirectory is loggedon. Your code give localmachine hostname.

Answer (score 1):

this is  an utility from Systernal that solve your needs:

[PsLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx)

`PsLoggedOn` determines who is logged on by scanning the keys under the `HKEY_USERS` key in all domain computer. You need `local administrative credential` of client computers.